# Creating an iframe content with elements created by the parent Document object

Tags: javascript, dom, iframe

I'm writing a code which fills dynamically an `iframe` content. The sample below relies on the `document` object of the `iframe`:

```
function createIFrame() {
    var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
    iframe.onload = function() {fillIFrame(iframe);};
}

function fillIFrame(iframe) {
    // Creating an "header" element with the embedded Document object.
    var ifdocument = iframe.contentDocument;
    var header = ifdocument.createElement("header");
    header.appendChild(ifdocument.createTextNode("Header."));
    ifdocument.body.appendChild(header);
}
```

If I rewrite the `iframe` filling this way, using the parent `document` object:

```
function fillIFrame(iframe) {
   // Using the parent Document object
   var header = document.createElement("header");
   header.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Header."));
   iframe.contentDocument.body.appendChild(header);
}
```

It still works. Is there any relevant difference between these two approaches?

Comment: why use an iframe if all you do is fill it in with js?

Comment: @Pete it's just a sample, it doesn't show the whole context. By the way your question sounds like it's a bad practice to generate dynamically an `iframe` content through javascript. Is that what you meant?